# Get a CSV file from an EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jpa, entitymanager

My company asked me to improve one method from an older project.
The task is to create a csv file from a SQL table (`select *`) and download with a jsp, the main problem there aren't any Model class and there are a lot of table and I prefer don't create many one, my idea it was to get the list of rows and than for each entity get one row

The service class

```
public List<String> searchBersaniFile() {
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(SQL_SELECT_REPNORM_BERSANI);
        List<String> resultList = (List<String>) q.getResultList(); //I get CastClassException here 
        System.out.println(resultList);
        if (resultList == null) {
            resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

The main class:

```
try (ServletOutputStream outServlet = response.getOutputStream()) {

            switch (flowType) {
        
            case STATO_BERSANI:
                listResult = awpSapNewRepository.searchBersaniFile();
                break;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String str;
            for (String result : listResult) {
                System.out.println(result);
                str = result.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").replaceAll(",", ";");
                System.out.println(str);
                buffer.append(str);
                buffer.append("\r\n");

            }

            String fileName = buildFileName(flowType);

            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            ;
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            outServlet.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());
            outServlet.flush();
        }
```

I tried to get to get in String as you can see on top  (via debug I see it returns like this: [column1, column2, column3][column1,....])
Do you have any idea how can I get the csv without create any model?

Comment: What does `getResultList` return? Can you share the stack trace of the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: @dan1st It returns a List, I even tried to save in the object but as I print I get the andress memorries and not the values

Comment: It returns a `List` - ok but does it return a `List<String>` (are all elements `String`s)? And still - Can you share the stack trace of the `ClassCastException`?